# How to rest or empty input field in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I am using `react-final-form` library  .so in which I have one checkbox , on click of checkbox it shows textfield . User can enter text in text field .but if you `uncheck the checkbox` text retain in textfield .

**Steps to reproduce  this bug**

Checked the check box

Enter “abc” text in input field

Unchecked the checkbox

Again checked the checkbox.Textfied retain `abc` text.

```
<FieldPrefix prefix="app1">
  <div>
    <label>
      app1
      <PrefixedField name="appStatus" component="input" type="checkbox" />
    </label>
  </div>
  {values.app1 && values.app1.appStatus ? (
    <div>
      <label>City</label>
      <PrefixedField
        name="city"
        component="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="City"
      />
    </div>
  ) : null}
</FieldPrefix>;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-field-56zpm
[image]

https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form

Comment: Firstly pick value for textbox from a state variable and hook onChange event for textbox and change state accordingly. When you reset it just update the state variable to an empty string and you will see it clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use value props in the input field where put a state like

```
<div>
    <label>City</label>
    <PrefixedField
    name="city"
    component="input"
    type="text"
    placeholder="City"
    value = {this.state.valueForInput}
    />
</div>
```

and clear the state valueForInput when user uncheck the check box

Comment: please use `react final form ` api

Comment: well why ? can you elaborate it !

Comment: yeah but they do have a value props where you use it

Comment: I think there is no need to add create state unnecessary ..react final form do for us

Comment: actually they will also do the same process using a state , as react render will never update unless you update a state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197371/discussion-between-kazi-hasan-ali-and-joy).

Answer (score 0):

Add this `(values.app1 && values.app1.city?values.app1.city="":null)` instead of the null in the ternary expression.

```
{values.app1 && values.app1.appStatus ? (
                <div>
                  <label>City</label>
                  <PrefixedField
                    name="city"
                    component="input"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="City"
                  />
                </div>
              ) : (values.app1 && values.app1.city?values.app1.city="":null)}
```